# Detectar aparición elemento luego de una carga JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Buenas ando con un problema estoy utilizando TamperMonkey con jquery, en una página la cual cuando se entra a la misma muestra un icono de carga y en el sitio no hay ningún elemento más que ese mismo, una vez cargado muestra todo el sitio como debe ser y desaparece dicho elemento, el problema es que necesito introducir un elemento en el header del sitio pero no puedo ya que cuando intento está en la fase de carga y dicho elemento no existe aún, proble con el document.ready pero entra en funcionamiento un poco antes de que se muestren los elementos (header y demás). Necesitaría detectar cuando aparece el header o algo así. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Gaston, Te sugiero revisar [ask]-

Comment: Tu elemento tiene alguna id o clase ?

Comment: Lo que hago es llamar al selector mismo, con Jquery $("header") el problema es que no se como darme cuenta cuando ese elemento haya sido creado o insertado en el html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una función, la cual recibe el elemento y una función a ejecutar.

El elemento en este caso funciona con TAG, pero también puede ser una clase, una ID , etc

Chequeamos si existe el elemento con ese TAG, cada 100ms, por lo cual asignamos el intervalo a una variable, para que, tan pronto como el nodo exista, se elimina el intervalo y se ejecuta la función.

```
var wait = (e, funct) => {
          var r = setInterval(() => {
              if(document.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]) {
                clearInterval(r);
                funct();
              }
          }, 100);
        };
```

**Y lo ejecutas como:**

```
wait(TAG del elemento , funcion )
```